# Capture Value from textfield then macth with radio buttons value using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Everyone I got stuck in one problem I have two textbox(length*breadth) as shown in screenshot first we have two capture the entered value then we have two match with nearest value from dimension

**Example**

Lets say we have entered 71 and 29 in this case first we have to check nearest value for 71, so nearest value for 71 is 72(72*30,72*36), now we have to match second value 29 so nearest value is 30 then **our output is 72*30**

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("tmcp_textfield_7").addEventListener("blur", getValue);
document.getElementById("tmcp_textfield_8").addEventListener("blur", getValue);
function getValue() {
var entered = document.getElementById('tmcp_textfield_7');
var entered1 = document.getElementById('tmcp_textfield_8');
    alert(entered.value);
    alert(entered1.value);
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <li class="tmcp-field-wrap_tmcp_textfield_7">
    <label for="tmcp_textfield_7"></label>
      <input placeholder="Length" minlength="2" maxlength="4" class="tmcp-field dimension-layer-entersize1 tm-epo-field tmcp-textfield tm-valid" name="tmcp_textfield_5" type="number">

 </li>
     <li class="tmcp-field-wrap_tmcp_textfield_8">
    <label for="tmcp_textfield_8"></label>
      <input placeholder="Breadth" minlength="2" maxlength="4" class="tmcp-field dimension-layer-entersize2 tm-epo-field tmcp-textfield tm-valid" name="tmcp_textfield_6" type="number" >

 </li>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You miss attribute `id` in `text` inputs, so give to them id like this :**

```
<input id="tmcp_textfield_7" ...

<input id="tmcp_textfield_8" ....
```

**And insert jquery code like this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#tmcp_textfield_7 ").on("blur",function(){
        
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
        
    })
    $("#tmcp_textfield_8").on("blur",function(){
        
         var value = $(this).val();
         alert(value);
        
    })
    
    
})
```

```html
   <li class="tmcp-field-wrap_tmcp_textfield_7">
    <label for="tmcp_textfield_7"></label>
      <input id="tmcp_textfield_7" placeholder="Length" minlength="2" maxlength="4" class="tmcp-field dimension-layer-entersize1 tm-epo-field tmcp-textfield tm-valid" name="tmcp_textfield_5" type="number">

 </li>
     <li class="tmcp-field-wrap_tmcp_textfield_8">
    <label for="tmcp_textfield_8"></label>
      <input id="tmcp_textfield_8" placeholder="Breadth" minlength="2" maxlength="4" class="tmcp-field dimension-layer-entersize2 tm-epo-field tmcp-textfield tm-valid" name="tmcp_textfield_6" type="number" >

 </li>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct but how can I map entered value with checkboxses ...